# transpose the rows to column when pattern found

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

Here is the sample file which I was to process. I thought of using keyword "description" as some sort of RS but don't know how to do that ,also its not consistant.

Background: I am processing a log file which contains, date/time stamp (APR12) in first line and in second line there is a description about the log. This description is availabele for few logs and missig for few.

```
001 APR12 aaa bbb
Description: This is a test file.
002 APR12 aaa bbb
Description: This is another test file.
003 APR12 aaa XXX
004 APR12 aaa bbb
Description: This is another,after skipping one.
```

## Desired output:

```
001 APR12 aaa bbb Description: This is a test file.
002 APR12 aaa bbb Description: This is another test file.
003 APR12 aaa XXX
004 APR12 aaa bbb Description: This is another,after skipping one.
```

Comment: If I rephrase it I do think the purpose is to remove the `\n` on the preceding line when the first char is not a numbe, to get all on the same line. `sed 's/\n([^0-9])/ \1/' file` shoud do the trick (replace "newline not followed by a number" by "space" and the "not a number" captured character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]/?rs:FS), $0; rs=RS} END{print ""}' file
001 APR12 aaa bbb Description: This is a test file.
002 APR12 aaa bbb Description: This is another test file.
003 APR12 aaa XXX
004 APR12 aaa bbb Description: This is another,after skipping one.
```

Comment: I don't get the reason of the empty print in END

Comment: newlines are only printed BEFORE each line that starts with a digit, never at the end of any line, so you need to print a newline after all lines are processed.

Comment: didn't notice the printf format had no \n :(. Sorry

Comment: You're welcome. If you're worried about printing a blank line given an empty input file, change the print in the END to be `printf "%s", rs`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a newline every time the current line does not begin with "Description":

```
awk 'NR>1 && !/^Description/{print ""}{printf "%s ", $0}' file
```

The `NR>1` prevents a newline from being added at the start of the output.

You may also want to add an `END` block to add a newline to the end of the output, if any lines were processed: `END{if(NR)print ""}`.

Comment: That will add a trailing blank char to the end of every line. That's something I always try to avoid since it's easy not to do it and since it's not visible the OP might not notice it during testing but it could mess up their real data later.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\n\(Description\)/ \1/;P;D' file
```

Read pairs of lines throughout the file and replace the newline with a space if the second line of the pair begins `Description`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ':a
N;$!ba
s/\n\([^0-9]\)/ \1/g' YourFile
```

- Until you don't have huge file (loaded in memory).
- join line that are not starting with number

If you have a GNU sed version after 4.2.2 that allow `-z` ([-Z option](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62m)). Thanks to @JJoao for this optimized code.

```
sed -z 's/\n\(^[0-9]\)/ \1/g' YourFile
```

Comment: `sed -z 's/\n\(^[0-9]\)/ \1/g'` ?

Comment: `-z` is not very often available (does it load the file at once ?). If it is the case and `-z` available, your form is lot better than mine

Comment: `-z` is from gnu sed (very popular but not universal) and stands from "null separated 'lines'" -- we dont have nulls so it slurps the file into memory. I believe it is very similar to your solution :)

Comment: i know GNU exist in the univers :-)  but this is the `-z` option that i don't find on my systems (Red hat) and the web source i have. And yes, in this case, you got the best shoot

Comment: got it, i adapt the reply with you info

Comment: I thought it was older... your "if" makes sense! 4.2.2 = Dec'2012 it is relatively recent...+1

Answer (score 0):

Probably too complicated, but here comes a solution with `sed`:

```
# Does the line contain description?

# Yes ...
/Description/{
    # Exchange hold and pattern space
    x
    # Append hold space to pattern space
    # separated by newline 
    G
    # Remove that newline by a space
    s/\n\+/ /gp 
}

# No ...
/Description/! {
    # Exchange hold and pattern buffer
    x
    # The hold buffer contains a prefix line
    /Description/! {
        # Print it
        p
    }
    # Exchange hold and pattern buffer again
    x
    # Store current line in the hold buffer   
    h   
}
```

Comment: That won't print the line `003 APR12 aaa XXX`.

Comment: I suspect you needed to add the blood of newt when the moon was full. Or maybe it's the missing symbol for Ra.... :-). (yes, I'm suggesting sed scripts for handling multi-line input are incomprehensible, magical incantations).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p0e 's!\n(?=Des)! !g'
```

(untested) -- It loads all the file into memory...